# Could not open configuration file bin/conf/httpd.conf: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

I installed wamp server but I cannot start the Apache service because of the following error,  'Could not open configuration file bin/conf/httpd.conf: The system cannot find the path specified'.

I figured this out by looking into Event Viewer. The actual path for the http.conf file is wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/http.conf.

I tried copying the folder conf and putting in the bin folder but the same error showed up when I started the Apache service using the Wamp server icon in the system tray. Please help me!!

The actual error message in the Event Viewer was: 
"The Apache service named  reported the following error:

> > > httpd.exe: Could not open configuration file bin/conf/httpd.conf: The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: What was the actual Event Viewer error message. Add it to your question, not as a comment

Comment: Also remove the copied `conf` folder from the `apache2.4.9/bin` folder. That way - only confusion lies

Comment: deleted the file still same result.

Comment: That was not a solution, just a clean up suggestion as that folder should not be there! Did you change anything after installing WAMPServer.

Comment: no I did not change anything ,only copied. conf file from the wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9 folder to the wamp/bin folder( and tried starting Apache services, only to find the same error) and after your suggetion deleted that copied file.

Comment: Are you sure you didnt edit any of WAMPServer's files with `notepad` and accidentally save them? That can add a `.txt` extension for the saved file and then things get into this NOT FOUND situation. Make sure you have `Hide known File Extensions` set OFF in Explorer and check the actual filenames of anything you may have edited.

Comment: no I did not edit any file, I crosschecked after setting Hide known file extensions OFF in the Folder Options dialogue box.

Comment: I cannot think why its looking in the wrong place for the `httpd.conf` file, unless something went wrong with the install. Try uninstalling WAMPServer and then manually delete the `\wamp` folder. Then re-install.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple: install apache on C:\ (open the downloaded zip file and copy the apache folder to C:). Don't install it on the Program Files folder!!. You can install it in your user folder too...

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find that you have had an Apache installed on your system before and its finding an old httpd.conf file.

All WAMPServers files are under the `\wamp\` folder, so do a search for `httpd.conf` and delete any that are outside the `\wamp\` folder structure.

Comment: nope, no files httpd.conf outside the wamp directory.